# Mixed Maths about speed and distance

Tags: calculus

There are 2 ends. Namely south end a north end. Distance between both ends are 120metres 
If 2 toy cars drive from both ends at same time when will they meet.
If the toy car from south to north goes in a speed of 12 metres per second and the toy car from north to south goes in a speed of 8 metres per second!
I got an answer as 7.5 seconds. But I'm not sure with it. Please big help if you can solve this out.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I think you misunderstood a key aspect of this site. This is more about *helping* you find the right answer then giving you answers to arbitrary problems. For example, if you were to give us what you've tried, where you've looked, what you've read to answer the problem, and describe why you aren't satisfied/doubt what you've come across, I'm sure others would help. Also, choosing a descriptive title that described the content would help. For more, I recommend reading [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9754)

Comment: HINT: How many seconds does it take for one car driving at $12+8$ meters per second to complete a distance of $120$ meters?

Answer (score 0):

i think if you think putting both of then on a belt and drive the belt at $8 \, m/sec$   so that the slower car stays put at the same place. the faster will go at $20 \, m/sec$ and all the $120 \, m $ in $6 \, sec$ to meet the stationary one.